# $\sum\frac{b_j}{1+b_j}$ diverge or converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

Showing the series if $b_j>0$

and $\sum b_j$ converges then what can you say about the sum of

$\sum\frac{b_j}{1+b_j}$

I think I can use the comparison test here I think

since $\sum\frac{b_j}{1+b_j}<\sum b_j$ and $\sum b_j$ converges then my other series
converges.

Comment: Indeed you can use Comparison.  I would say that for all $j$, we have $\frac{b_j}{1+b_j}\lt b_j$, and therefore by Comparison $\dots$.

Comment: if $b_j/(1+b_j) < b_j$ you will be done.

Comment: Comparison test will work as $ \frac{1}{1+b_{j}} < 1$

Comment: Ok that makes sense.

Comment: Actually you can prove that the converse holds as well. Each of the two series is convergent if and only if the other is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_j\geq 0$.
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{b_j}{1+b_j}<\infty \iff \sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j<\infty  $$

For the implication, since $\frac{b_j}{1+b_j}\to 0$, it's easy to show that $(b_j)_j$ is bounded, and thus that $0\leq b_j\leq C\frac{b_j}{1+b_j}$  for a certain $C>0$. The reciprocally is obvious since $\frac{1}{1+b_j}\leq 1$.